# passing a variable with window.opener javascript

Tags: javascript, window, window.opener

In the first page I have

```
window.tmpstr = 'aaaaaa';
window.open ('second.php','_self',false);
```

in second.php

```
alert(window.opener.tmpstr)
```

This alerts 'undefined'.  when I change '_self' to '_blank' it works.  How can I pass the variable when I want the new window to open in the same window.

Comment: ... why aren't you either sending the data to the second page via the server OR loading the second page async so that you don't refresh the entire document?

Comment: This is a mobile site and I'm trying to limit the calls to the server.  I get the data from the server on the first page and its huge.

Comment: Are you trying to build a single-page webapp?

Comment: Theres three pages that all need to share the same json string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, not like that.
By calling `window.open` using `_self`, you simply redirect the page to the `second.php` url.

Options you can use are :

- Adding it as a parameter using the hash tag (second.php#tmpstr=aaaaaa
- Using cookies (there is a nice jQuery cookie plugin)
- Moving your whole page into a iFrame (not recommended) and redirecting only the main frame.